# Can the Windows 7 Easy Migration tool put the migration file on the C: drive?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, installation, migration

I have a Windows XP installation on a 698 GB partition with 448 GB free. I don't currently have an external drive that will fit my migration data, but the partition will.

Can I put the migration file on the C: drive? From what I am reading, doing a custom clean install will move the C: drive contents into a hidden windows.old folder. I am thinking I would be able to move the migration file into a "regular" folder and then use it to import my old settings and files.

Would this work, or am I going to lose the migration file during the clean install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded from XP to Windows 7 a couple days ago.

From what I remember, the contents of C:\Documents and Settings, C:\Program Files, and C:\Windows are moved into a new folder named C:\Windows.old.  None of the other folder on my C:\ were moved or deleted.

So if you are just looking to copy files from your current user profile to your new Windows 7 profile, you should be ok.

This is assuming you don't modify the drive partition and/or format the drive.

Note: Even though I say it's possible to retrieve your "migration" data after the upgrade without the external drive, I still highly recommend you find a way to back up your stuff just in case.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks. I have my important data in an online backup, just in case.